# Is it 'lesser' or 'less' when describing an amount of water?

Tags: difference, comparative-constructions, uncountable-nouns

From the following sentences, which one is more grammatically correct?

- Carbohydrates in diet need less amount of water in comparison to proteins and fats.
- Carbohydrates in diet need less**er** amount of water in comparison to proteins and fats

I personally think the second one should be correct because we are comparing carbohydrates to fats and proteins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is quite right. In general, you would probably want to say either

> Carbohydrates in the diet need **less water** in comparison to proteins and fats.

or

> Carbohydrates in the diet need **a smaller amount of water** in comparison to proteins and fats.

At a stretch, you might possibly say

> Carbohydrates in the diet need **a lesser amount of water** in comparison to proteins and fats.

but it sounds less idiomatic than the other two options.

---

You've hit upon a rather tricky part of English, the usage of *less* vs *lesser* vs *smaller*. In general, you can compare [*uncountable*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/countable-nouns) or *mass* nouns (like water) using the word *less*:

> There is **less milk** in my glass than in yours. 
>   The water is **less** than one inch deep.

You use *smaller* to compare *countable* nouns:

> My glass is **smaller** than yours.
>   I want the **smaller** cookie, please.

In your sentence, you have the countable, compound noun *[an] amount of water*. Because it is countable, you need to have an article in there, and you need to use the comparative term *smaller*:

> Carbohydrates in **the**<sup>1</sup> diet need ***a smaller* amount** of water in comparison to proteins and fats.

Alternatively, you could drop the phrase *[an] amount* and have just the mass/uncountable noun water (which doesn't need an article), in which case you would use the term *less* for comparison:

> Carbohydrates in **the** diet need **less** a̶m̶o̶u̶n̶t̶ ̶o̶f **water** in comparison to proteins and fats.

---

So why not *lesser*?

*Lesser* is a more specialized case. For one thing, it can only be used attributively (right before a noun), and only with count nouns. When we use it comparatively, it most often refers to *quality* or *importance* rather than *quantity*:

> Joe is a **lesser** man than Pete.
>   *Titus Andronicus* is often regarded as one of Shakespeare's **lesser** works.

It can be used to refer to quantity, but only with a few specialized count nouns of amount or quantity:

> I like raspberries and, to a **lesser degree**, strawberries.
>   There is a **lesser amount** of money invested in Plan A than in Plan B.
>   A **lesser number** of citizens are voting nowadays than in years past.

However, while all of these are to some extent grammatical, only the first sounds fully idiomatic to my ear; for the rest, I would prefer to replace *lesser* with *smaller*. An [Ngram comparing usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lesser%20amount%2Clesser%20number%2Clesser%20degree%2Csmaller%20amount%2Csmaller%20number%2Csmaller%20degree&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clesser%20amount%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clesser%20number%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clesser%20degree%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmaller%20amount%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmaller%20number%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmaller%20degree%3B%2Cc0) suggests this trend is widespread:

### [image: Google Ngram comparing lesser amount,lesser number,lesser degree,smaller amount,smaller number,smaller degree]

<sup>1</sup> The word *diet* is countable, so it needs an article here. You could also use a possessive pronoun: *Carbohydrates in **your** diet*.

So while you *could* use it, *smaller* probably sounds better.

Answer (score 0):

> Carbohydrates in diet need less amount of water in comparison to proteins and fats.
>
> Carbohydrates in diet need lesser amount of water in comparison to proteins and fats.

Neither one is grammatically correct since *diet* is a countable noun and you're not comparing carbs to proteins and fats taken together. *In comparison to* is also needlessly verbose, leaving aside that it should really be *with*. The grammatically correct phrasing would be

> Dietary carbohydrates need less water than proteins or fats.
>
> Dietary carbohydrates need a lesser amount of water than proteins or fats.

Even then, neither sentence really makes sense. You should explain to the reader: *...need less water to/for what?*

Comment: While you've fixed the problems in your example sentences, I don't think you explain very well what you did to fix them or what they were. For example, why didn't you just use an article to fix the countable noun problem? "Carbohydrates in a diet need..." Also what happened to "amount"? Why is it there for lesser and not there for less? The question is about "less" and "lesser" but your answer doesn't really discuss either.

Comment: @ColleenV Feel free to reread the question and reread the answer, which answered it. Both were grammatically incorrect and less/lesser had nothing to do with the problem(s).

Comment: To address the specific requests, though, *carbohydrates in a diet* establishes a contrast with *carbohydrates outside a diet* which is bizarre→nonsensical. Kat intended *dietary* or *carbohydrates in your/one's diet*. *Dietary* is terser. Similarly, *amount* is necessary to make *water* countable when using *lesser* but is inappropriate for *less*.

Comment: It's just a suggestion for improving your answer that you can use or not use as you choose. I already know the answer to the questions in my comment. I wanted to point out that the author highlighted that less and lesser is what was confusing them (in their title) and you don't really explain the difference at all.

Answer (score -2):

The use of less or lesser can be used in this sentence with minor grammatical changes.

**Use of Less**

Carbohydrates in diet need **less water** in comparison to proteins and fats

**Use of Lesser**

Carbohydrates in diet need **a lesser amount of water** in comparison to proteins and fats

In the context, the second option would be better.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. As with lly, you've provided a correction, but without any explanation either of what you've corrected or why you consider the second option to be better. As a reminder, StackExchange seeks *definitive* answers to questions. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Thanks for having the decency for providing a reason for the down vote. Agreed, my answer was not sufficiently specific.

Comment: FWIW, I did not downvote.